# The type 'X' does not exist in the type 'X.X' error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, namespaces

The project structure is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3OTq.png).
How can I modify the project to compile?
What are the best practices in organizing a project structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't name a type the same as its namespace. That's always a bad idea. You can get round the issues in various ways, but it's ugly in many cases. Renaming either the type or the namespace would be much better.

In this *particular* case, you can just change your code to:

```
Application.Run(new NeuralNetwork());
```

... and that will refer to the type. But *don't* just do that - rename the type or namespace instead :)

Eric Lippert has a four part blog post series on the topic:

- [Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx)
- [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/11/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-two.aspx)
- [Part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/15/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-three.aspx)
- [Part 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/18/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-four.aspx)